# BitBlit/Copy from D2D1DeviceContext target D2D1Bitmap1 to HDC

Tags: c++, directx, gdi

For a past few days I was looking for an option to use DirectX 2D in a pattern where I can render to 'something' and then this 'something' - use as input to other drawing.

All of RenderTargets like Hwnd, Dc, Wic bitmap - does not allow to do it (Wic target does not use HW acceleration).

Only one way I found is D2D1DeviceContext
[M$ document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts)

There I can create ID2D1Bitmap1 (which also, when created with CPU_READ flag - can be mapped and read) which can be set as target.

So far - so good, all is working fine.
However, at the end, we all want to display the result of drawing onto a user screen and for this purpose - we need to pass it to some WinAPI DC.

I've done it this way.

Create ID2D1Bitmap1 with GDI compatibility

```
D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties =
        D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
            D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_GDI_COMPATIBLE,
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
        );
```

Get from ID2D1DeviceContext - ID2D1GdiInteropRenderTarget

```
_d2d1context->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&_d2d1GDIinterface))
```

And finally - using this interface, I get DC and use GDI function BitBlt

```
void paste_bitmap_into_dc(HDC dc, ID2D1Bitmap& bitmap) {
    _d2d1context->SetTarget(&bitmap);
    _d2d1context->BeginDraw();
    HDC new_dc;
    _d2d1GDIinterface->GetDC(D2D1_DC_INITIALIZE_MODE_COPY, &new_dc);

    BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, bitmap.size().x, bitmap.size().y, new_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    RECT update_rect;
    SetRect(&update_rect, 0, 0, 0, 0); // i don't want to actually update bitmap on ID2D1DeviceContext
    _d2d1GDIinterface->ReleaseDC(&update_rect);
    _d2d1context->EndDraw();
}
```

That works but I'm not sure that this is a proper (fastest) way, since there is DC created and its coppied twice (hopefuly - on HW side): from target ID2D1Bitmap to this new DC and then from new DC to input DC.
And actually this method is more for drawing with GDI on D2D1 content (ReleaceDC have argument which part of bitmap to update).

Someone could help/confirm this is the way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see why you use BitBlt and don't use  ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::DrawBitmap or ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap

Comment: @Castorix - I cannot draw bitmap which was created by other render target. Which means, if I use DeviceContext as render target - bitmaps created by it cannot be drawn by HwndRender target. And why I use DeviceContext not Hwnd(or DC)RenderTarger is explained at the beggining.

Comment: I never use BitBlt() in Direct2D. For particular cases, I use ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateCompatibleRenderTarget, and if I want to use ID2D1Effect for example, I get ID2D1DeviceContext with ::QueryInterface
then ::DrawImage or ::DrawBitmap

Comment: Hmm, you say, that if I create fe. HwndRender target, I will be able to query ID2D1DeviceContext by using QueryInterface method? That would probably do the trick.